# Android Studio: Graphics are cut

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the Views attached to each other in the following order:

Activity->RelativeLayout->RelativeLayout->Text

When I change the Y of one of the Text attached to the inner RelativeLayout, parts of it are cut.

Here's a screenshot:

http://s28.postimg.org/ypmvrjz25/image.png

I'm coding purely in Java, no XML.

What's going on?

Comment: can you post your xml code?

Comment: There's no XML code I add things purely in Java.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one layout is overlapping on another because the menu bar is pushing it down. If you just want the text centered I would suggest setting that in the parameters like so.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

This places the text in the center if that is what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a layout in front of another layout without any layout cutting the other? What I want is to be able to move things freely, rather than just center in this specific case.

Comment: He also stated in a comment that he is doing this purely through Java (although including that in the question would have been nice)

Comment: Nicholas - I modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jonathan Whalen suggested you probably have some overlap, I suggest you to change your relative layouts background color to see wich one is overlapping the text. Also try to not use fixed height for the layouts but use wrap_content instead, as fixed dims are frequently the cause of layouts overlap.

Comment: wrap_content didn't solve the problem.

If I find which one is overlapping the text what should I do about it?

Comment: Mmmm that's weird, are you sure both relative layouts use wrap_content? Can you share your java code? Or post a screenshot with the colored background layouts?